# Cleanest way to use multiple values in a complex routine?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, while-loop, software-design

See the following pseudocode snippet that approximates my situation:

```
function foo () {
  for ( velocity=0; velocity<100; velocity++ ) {
    root1 = computeRoot1();
    root2 = computeRoot2();
    // do a bunch of computation with root1
    // if result of computation is undesirable, do computations again with root2 
  }
```

So, basically I want to do the computations in the body of the `for` loop with `root1`, and then `root2` if `root1`'s computation result is invalid.

My first instinct was the obvious approach, to wrap the computation in a help function, but I'm not sure this is the most clear approach. I'm trying for good collocation of information in my code, and a function call for code that will be executed at most twice (per iteration) defeats that goal without providing a great deal of conciseness to my code.

I was thinking perhaps a `for` loop like:

```
for ( root=root1; root1IsInvalid==true || bothRootsInvalid==true; root=root2 )
```

or a `while` with similar functionality. But I'm certainly open to other suggestions

As someone reading this code, which approach would make it the most readable and concise to you?

As an aside, I'm writing this particular function in JavaScript, but language-agnostic solutions would be awesome.

EDIT: clarified code snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several basic approaches:

1. Put the values in an array and use a `for` loop to run the same code on each item in the array, perhaps stopping the iterations when some condition is met.
2. Create a function that does the computation and then just write code that calls the function on the first one, then the second one and so on.
3. Create a `while` loop and repeat your code until some condition is met.

The first option is easier to extend to N items.  The second option is perhaps simpler for just two items.

You can make the computation function be a local function (declared and used inside the function you are currently executing) so it doesn't add to the global namespace and your code remains more encapsulated.

I'm also not sure what you intend to be doing with this line:

```
root1, root2 = computeRoots();
```

But, it is only assigning the value to `root2` and it looks like you probably want `var` in front of these to define them as local variables.

Comment: There's a trade-off in the sense that the first is co-calculating, so you always do twice the work, while the latter would only recalculate on the first being "invalid". Right?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - presumably, you would test some condition in the `for` loop and decide whether to continue with the additional iterations or not - breaking out of the `for` loop if done.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the input, I think #1 is what I'm looking for. Also, updated my code snippet for clarity

Answer (score 1):

If eager evaluation is OK, you can collect your roots into an array and use `roots.filter(isinvalid)` to take out the invalid ones; then just use the first item in the resulting array.

If you need lazy evaluation, you can generalize this into a function that lazily evaluates a function over an array until a non-null result is found:

```
// call fn on items in arr until fn returns non-null
// returns [item, result]
// if result===false, no true value was returned
function firstNotNull(fn, arr) {
    var i, length, item, result=null;
    for (i = 0, length=arr.length; i < length; i++) {
        item = arr[i];
        result = fn(item);
        if (result!==null) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return [item, result];
}


function rootComputations(root) {
    var computationResult = null;
    if (root==1) {
        computationResult = 1;
    }
    return computationResult;
}

function computeRoots() {
    return [0,1];
}

function foo() {
    var velocity, roots, root, result, computations;
    for (velocity = 0; velocity < 100; velocity++) {
        roots = computeRoots();
        computations = firstNotNull(rootComputations, roots);
        console.log(computations);
        root = computations[0];
        result = computations[1];
    }
}

foo();
```

You can generalize `firstNotNull()` even further:

```
// call fn on items in arr until cond(fn(item)) returns true
// returns [item, fn(item)], or null if unsatisfied
function firstSatisfying(cond, fn, arr) {
    var i, length, item, fnitem, result=null;
    for (i = 0, length=arr.length; i < length; i++) {
        item = arr[i];
        fnitem = fn(item);
        if (cond(fnitem)) {
            result = [item, fnitem];
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var firstNotNull = firstSatisfying.bind(null, function(item){return item!==null;});
```

You now have a generic function for taking the first of a list of things that satisfies any condition you want.

ECMAScript 5 added many methods which make *eager* functional application over arrays much easier, but Javascript doesn't have any native facilities for *lazy* evaluation. If this is something you think you'll be needing often, consider using [stream.js](http://streamjs.org), which provides a "stream" datatype with methods for partial application.  Using stream.js, your logic would look like this:

```
// rootStream should be a function which returns a Stream
// It should construct a stream with the first root produced
// and a function that returns the remaining roots.
// Since I don't know how you get your roots, I'll use a stupid example:
function rootStream() {
    return new Stream(0, function(){
        return new Stream(1);
    });
}

function isvalid(root) {
    return root===1;
}

Stream.range(0,100)
.walk(function(v){
    //v doesn't seem to be used?
    var firstvalid = rootStream().filter(isvalid).head();
    console.log(firstvalid);
});
```